# There is bug in calculating Fibonacci numbers - Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads, fibonacci, state-monad

I solve different problems in some judging systems. Today I want to calculate Fibonacci numbers with `State Monad`. My code works well and it pass all my tests. But there is some error (one test is failed), which I can not determine.

My code is:

```
fib :: Int -> Integer
fib n = fst $ execState (replicateM n fibStep) (0,1)

fibStep :: State (Integer,Integer) ()
fibStep = do modify (\(a, b) -> (b, a + b))
```

Can you help me to find the error? I don't know, where error is.

Comment: Well, _what_ is the error? What test fails and in which way?

Comment: @leftaroundabout, this judging system does not give me test, which is failed. My code calculate wrong fib number for some `n`. I brute many `n`, but I can not find error.

Comment: With this implementation, `fib 1 = 1`. If you need `fib 1 = 0` then you need to `replicateM (n-1) fibStep`. Otherwise this code looks fine.

Comment: Can you link to the description of the problem you are solving, please? (Or include the problem statement from the judge word-for-word here.)

Comment: @Mokosha, `fib 1 = 1` according to definition of fib numbers of this system.

Comment: @DanielWagner, this is a private system (you do not have access to it). The full task is: "Write a function that computes Fibonacci numbers using State monad.". Also, first 3 lines of my code given from system. Also, there is one test: `fib 7 = 13`.

Comment: What does the system expect when `fib` is given a negative number as input?

Comment: @GPhilip, the system expect `0` in this case.

Comment: @Denis Perhaps you should correspond with whoever is in charge of the judge. There is not much room to hide a problem in such short code!

Comment: @DanielWagner, I thought about this step. Therefore I created this topic as last chance before contacting with support.

Comment: The do syntax isn't necessary if you only have one monadic statement :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your code IS correct, tested using a naive implementation `fib0` from [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/The_Fibonacci_sequence)

```
import Control.Monad.State

fib :: Int -> Integer
fib n = fst $ execState (replicateM n fibStep) (0,1)

fibStep :: State (Integer,Integer) ()
fibStep = do modify (\(a, b) -> (b, a + b))

fib0 0 = 0
fib0 1 = 1
fib0 n = fib0 (n-1) + fib0 (n-2)
```

I tried:

```
*Main> map (\x -> fib x - fib0 x) [1..25]
```

and got

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Your function seems to give identical results as expected ones.